# Avoid escaping new line with XmlElement SetAttribute

Tags: .net, xml, powershell

I am using PowerShell to encode an XML attribute that contains new lines. The XML spec does not specifically say that newlines in attributes are illegal, and the consumer of the XML (which I don't control) does not seem to like them.

I would like to produce

```
<Something>
    <Bla Text='
        here is a
        multi-line string
    '></Bla>
</Something>
```

The code I'm using is something like this:

```
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.psbase.PreserveWhitespace = $true
$xml.Load($filename)

$bla = $xml.CreateElement('Bla')
$bla.SetAttribute('Text', $multiLineString)
$xml.Something.AppendChild($bla)
```

It produces output like this:

```
<Bla Text="&#xD;&#xA;    here is a&#xD;&#xA;    multi-line string&#xD;&#xA;    " />
```

I'd like the newlines preserved. I'm less concerned with the quoting.

Comment: `PreserveWhitespace` only affects whitespace between elements, not within attributes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it does in [3.3.3 Attribute Normalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize) (emphasis mine)

> For each character, entity reference, or character reference in the unnormalized attribute value, beginning with the first and continuing to the last, do the following:
>   * For a character reference, append the referenced character to the normalized value.
>   * For an entity reference, recursively apply step 3 of this algorithm to the replacement text of the entity.
>   * **For a white space character (#x20, #xD, #xA, #x9), append a space character (#x20) to the normalized value.**
>   * For another character, append the character to the normalized value.

Note that later on it talks about how you can declare the attribute in a way that matches what you are seeing, specifically as CDATA if I am reading it correctly.

However an important thing to note about XML is if you want a minor enough change you can always transform the string afterwards.

For instance in the above `xml = xml.Replace("&#xD;", "\r").Replace("&#A;", "\n")`. Assuming you don't have the newlines in a weird spot this should work.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see that when I was skimming through the spec. I take it back. Sadly, the program that's consuming the XML is expecting it without escaping, so I'm still trying to find a solution. I'll probably go with the post-processing as you suggest, since there are only a couple of attributes like this in the file.

Comment: @ParchedSquid: Technically it *should* accept `&#d;` as equivalent to `\r` but that is the reality of XML.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your multi-line string as a here-string:

```
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.psbase.PreserveWhitespace = $true
$xml.Load($filename)

$multiLineString = @'
here is a
        multi-line string
'@

$bla = $xml.CreateElement('Bla')
$bla.SetAttribute('Text', $multiLineString)
$xml.Something.AppendChild($bla)
```

See get-help about_quoting_rules for more information on using here-strings.

Comment: Thanks. It was unrelated to the question, so I didn't show how/where the $multiLineString came from, but that's basically what I'm doing.

Comment: I tested that with a test xml file, and it added that elememt as multi-line text.

Comment: For me, if I do that and read the value back out, it is a multi line string. But if you save the XML file, or look at the innerXml property as a string, it is encoded.